# ¿cómo activar un botón que esta desactivado haciendo click con otro botón?

Tags: javascript, html

Hace un par de días hice esta misma pregunta y me respondieron excelentes respuestas ahora mi siguiente pregunta es, cómo hacer que el evento que se activa en un botón al hacer clic se mantenga activo cuando se refresque la página.

```js
$('.jsBtn_1').on('click', function(){
   //Removemos el atributo 'disabled' del segundo botón, apenas se detecte un click en el primer botón
   $('.jsBtn_2').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="jsBtn_1">Botón 1</button>
<button class="jsBtn_2" disabled>Botón 2</button>
```

Comment: PERDÓN ERA EN LA PREGUNTA ERA QUE SE QUEDE CON EL MISMO EVENTO ACTIVADO CUANDO SE REFRESQUE LA PAGINA

Comment: Mejor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/247916/edit) la pregunta y corrige lo que sea necesario, quedará mucho más claro.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar `localStorage` para guardar un flag del estado del boton; si este estado esta activo; entonces el boton se mantendra activo aun cuando recargues la pagina; simplemente deberas cambiar el estado del boton en la funcion del click del primer boton.

**NOTA:** Este script no funciona en el entorno StackOverflow

```js
if (localStorage.getItem('active') === 'true') {
  document.querySelector('.jsBtn_2').removeAttribute('disabled')
}

$('.jsBtn_1').on('click', function() {
  //Removemos el atributo 'disabled' del segundo botón, apenas se detecte un click en el primer botón
  $('.jsBtn_2').removeAttr('disabled');
  localStorage.setItem('active', 'true')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="jsBtn_1">Botón 1</button>
<button class="jsBtn_2" disabled>Botón 2</button>
```

Comment: No copie ningun codigo; no hagas suposiciones... Mi codigo es JavaScript puro, habiendome fijado en la respuesta que mencionas, el utiliza jQuery

Comment: Lo siento, pero son idénticos. Siendo el del enlace publicado con anterioridad

Comment: De nuevo, no son identicos, lo mio esta hecho en JavaScript, y la respuesta que mencionas usa jQuery; simplemente son similares porque sigue la misma logica de utilizar `localStorage` que es lo mas sencillo para OP.